# Accessing useState hook from child

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Right now, each one of the children (SelectorButton), can toggle on and off, if it is toggled on, then the title of that component is added into the "current" array on the parent page, when it is toggled off, the title of that component is popped out of the array. I'm trying to set it up so that if the "current" array has more than one title in it(at least one button is pressed), a 'next' button is visible.

The issue I'm having right now is that the if statement that controls the button content, is always thinking that 'current.length' == 0, this is because it is not getting rerendered, it is looking at the initial state of 'current' when you first load the page.

I'm pretty sure I need to make 'current' a useState hook but have no clue how to pass that info into each component so it can get updated. I'm sorry if that explanation was a little hard to understand, Ill happily answer any questions. All help is greatly appreciated :)

parent page:

```
...
import SelectorButton from '../components/selectorButton';
const SignUpOne = ({ navigation }) => {
    //this gets updated as they click or click off a button
    //this hold the current pressed buttons
    //pretty sure this needs to be a state but Im not sure how to
    //pass this into children
    let current = []
    let nextButton

    if (current.length >= 1) {
        //next button is visible
        console.log('is visible')
        nextButton = <TouchableOpacity><Text>Next</Text></TouchableOpacity>
    } else {
        //its not visisble
        console.log('not visible')
        nextButton = <View></View>
    }

    const textFunction = () => {
        console.log(current)
    }

    return (


        <View style={styles.screen}>
            <ScrollView bounces={false}>
                <View style={{ margin: 20, flex: 1 }}>
                    {/*back button */}
                    <View style={{ width: '100%', flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between' }}>
                        <TouchableOpacity onPress={textFunction} style={styles.backButton}>
                            <Text>back</Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>


                        <View style={styles.backButton}>
                            <Text>hi</Text>
                        </View>
                    </View>
                    <View style={styles.stepNotify}>
                        <Text style={styles.stepText}>Step 1 of 3</Text>
                    </View>

                    <Text style={styles.question}>What are you looking to improve?</Text>

                    {/*this is where the actual buttons are*/}
                    <View style={styles.optionContainer}>

                        {/*top row of buttons */}
                        <View style={{
                            flexDirection: 'row',
                            justifyContent: 'space-between',
                            width: '100%',
                        }}>
                            {/*actual button item */}
                            <SelectorButton array={current} title='Health'>
                                <Text>icon</Text>
                            </SelectorButton>

                            <SelectorButton array={current} title='???'>
                                <Text>icon</Text>
                            </SelectorButton>
                        </View>

                        {/*middle row of buttons */}
                        <View style={styles.rowContainer}>
                            {/*actual button item */}
                            <SelectorButton array={current} title='Relationships'>
                                <Text>icon</Text>
                            </SelectorButton>

                            <SelectorButton array={current} title='Time Allocation'>
                                <Text>icon</Text>
                            </SelectorButton>
                        </View>

                        {/*final row of buttons */}
                        <View style={styles.rowContainer}>
                            {/*actual button item */}
                            <SelectorButton array={current} title='Career'>
                                <Text>icon</Text>
                            </SelectorButton>

                            <SelectorButton array={current} title='Mental Health'>
                                <Text>icon</Text>
                            </SelectorButton>
                        </View>

                    </View>
                </View>
            </ScrollView>
        </View >
    )
}
export default SignUpOne
...
```

The SelectorButton Component:

```
...
const SelectorButton = (props) => {
    //remember that it is rendered for each button seperatley
    //when active is == true, we want it to be added to an array,
    //if it is updated to false, we want to remove it from the array,
    //on submit, we want to push the remaining items to the user profile
    const [active, updateActive] = useState(false)
    //this has the

    const updateActiveHandler = () => {
        updateActive(prev => !prev)


        if (active == true) {
            console.log(props.title, 'is off')
            let index = props.array.indexOf(props.title)
            props.array.splice(index, 1)

        } else {
            console.log(props.title, 'is on')
            props.array.push(props.title)
        }
    }

    return (
        <View {...props} >
            {!active &&

                <View style={{ alignItems: 'center' }}>
                    <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={1} onPress={updateActiveHandler} style={styles.selectionButton}>
                        {props.children}
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                    <Text style={styles.selectionButtonLabel}>{props.title}</Text>
                </View>
            }

            {active &&
                <View style={{ alignItems: 'center' }}>
                    <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={1} onPress={updateActiveHandler} style={styles.pressedSelectionButton}>
                        {props.children}
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                    <Text style={styles.pressedSelectionLabel}>{props.title}</Text>
                </View>
            }


        </View>
    )
}

export default SelectorButton;
...
```

And for even more context, here is the page that is being rendered, SelectorButton is each or Boxes, when at least one is pressed (shown by turning blue) the next button shows) also need to make sure that all the pressed buttons are stored (added to a firebase user profile on the next signup step)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

```
const [current, setCurrent] = useState([])
```

is the correct solution so far as I can see. Then simply pass the setCurrent function to the necessary children as a prop. After that you'll be able to update current from the child components.

Comment: Also: props.array.push(props.title) -- you shouldn't pass props like this. Pass the title as you would any other value because otherwise your props will differ from state props and your app will start "forgetting" values real soon

Comment: ^ use .concat instead. Never directly modify state...

Comment: I figured that is what you would do yes, but I'm not sure how you would append each title to that hook? Think you could go a bit more into detail? how would you add and remove items when you cant use push/pop. I know there is the method of unpacking (...current, props.title) but im not sure that would work in this instance. you would need to pass in current aswell

Comment: I'm also just learning react so am no expert.
if you use concat, rather than push you'll get a new array, so not modifying state. The solution you suggested (...current, props.title) looks fine to me, and there's nothing wrong with passing in current, that's quite normal. Try: setTheArray([...theArray, newElement]);

Answer (score -1):

Like some answers already tell, you can pass setState, actually you can pass anything.

When you have `const [current, setCurrent] = useState("");` then you can pass current and setCurrent.

One other thing is when you don't need a state but you want to have a variable like a class attribute, then it's better to use "useRef":

```
const whatever = useRef("");
whatever.current = "new value";
console.log(whatever.current) // new value
```

The Problem with a normal variable that is created by let is e.g. you have the variable "current" and it get initialised with an empty array, and when you change it to something else and then when your component rerenders (becouse a state changed), then current will again be initialised with the empty array.

You can think that when your component rerenders, then it's like when react rendered your component at first time, the only difference is, that your state is now a different one then the first render.